# Correctly implement os.path.join() to replace string in file and directory names recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

A basic question on correct implementation of `os.path.join()`. I am probably missing something basic here.

Here in my below Python function I am trying to replace a string from a file-name or directory-name recursively at every nested (depth) level.

So the below function is working correctly to replace all occurrances of the string "free" and replace it with an empty string "" from the below file structure at each nested level

[image]

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        shutil.move(
            os.path.join(root, f), root+"/"+f.replace("free", "").strip()
        )
    for dr in dirs:
        shutil.move(
            os.path.join(root, dr), root+"/"+dr.replace("free", "").strip()
        )
```

And to execute the above I need to save the script as some_name.py, run it with the directory as argument:

```
python3 /path/to/some_name.py <directory>
```

But in the above script, I want to replace the part `root+"/"+f` with `os.path.join()` to make the code working in different operating systems.

But as soon as I refactor that part like below

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        shutil.move(
            os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f).replace("free", "").strip()
        )
    for dr in dirs:
        shutil.move(
            os.path.join(root, dr), root+"/"+dr.replace("free", "").strip()
        )
```

I am getting below error about `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/paul/Pictures/free-so/so/so/test.txt' -> '/home/paul/Pictures/-so/so/so/test.txt'`

Full error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/paul/Pictures/free-so/so/so/test.txt' -> '/home/paul/Pictures/-so/so/so/test.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "replace-string-in-directory-name-and-filenames-recursively.py", line 91, in <module>
    shutil.move(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 802, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/paul/Pictures/-so/so/so/test.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing "free" everywhere including in the path `root` and it cannot find the renamed directory to put the file in.

Try replacing

```py
shutil.move(
    os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f).replace("free", "").strip()
)
```

with:

```py
shutil.move(
    os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f.replace("free", "").strip())
)
```

You only want the replace to act on the filename (`f`) not on the `root` part of the path.

You can do a similar change on the `dirs` part as well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f.replace("free", "").strip()))`

**Ex:**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        shutil.move(
            os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f.replace("free", "").strip())
        )   # ! Update
    for dr in dirs:
        shutil.move(
            os.path.join(root, dr), os.path.join(root, dr.replace("free", "").strip())
        )
```